# How to change password in /etc/shadow to *

Tags: password, users, shadow

Looking at /etc/shadow, I see that system accounts have a * character in the password field, making it impossible to login as those accounts using a password.

I have a user account that I made, for which I now want a * as password in /etc/shadow.

I can't find any command line tool that does that, all I could do is manually edit shadow.

Is there any such command line tool?

Comment: `passwd -l user` is a good option.  Creating the account with `adduser --disabled-password` or `adduser --disabled-login` would also do this initially in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it impossible to log in to an account using a password, all that's needed is for the shadow password entry to be an invalid hash - the usual way to achieve that is to prepend a `!` character, which you can do with the `-l` or `--lock` option of the `passwd` command. From `man passwd`:

> ```
>   -l, --lock
>        Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
>        password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
>        encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).
>
>        Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be
>        able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).
>        To disable the account, administrators should use usermod
>        --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
>        Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their
>        password.
> ```

If you *really* want to replace the hashed password with the single character `*` however, you can do so with the `usermod` command:

```
sudo usermod -p '*' someuser
```

See also:

- [Difference between ! vs !! vs * in /etc/shadow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252016/difference-between-vs-vs-in-etc-shadow)